# Writing and reading headers with struct

Tags: python, struct

I have a file header which I am reading and planning on writing which contains information about the contents; version information, and other string values.

Writing to the file is not too difficult, it seems pretty straightforward:

```
outfile.write(struct.pack('<s', "myapp-0.0.1"))
```

However, when I try reading back the header from the file in another method:

```
header_version = struct.unpack('<s', infile.read(struct.calcsize('s')))
```

I have the following error thrown:

```
struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 2
```

How do I fix this error and what exactly is failing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Writing to the file is not too difficult, it seems pretty straightforward:

Not quite as straightforward as you think. Try looking at what's in the file, or just printing out what you're writing:

```
>>> struct.pack('<s', 'myapp-0.0.1')
'm'
```

As [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters) explain:

> For the `'s'` format character, the count is interpreted as the size of the string, not a repeat count like for the other format characters; for example, `'10s'` means a single 10-byte string, while `'10c'` means 10 characters. **If a count is not given, it defaults to 1.**

So, how do you deal with this?

1. Don't use `struct` if it's not what you want. The main reason to use `struct` is to interact with C code that dumps C `struct` objects directly to/from a buffer/file/socket/whatever, or a binary format spec written in a similar style (e.g. IP headers). It's not meant for general serialization of Python data. As Jon Clements points out in a comment, if all you want to store is a string, just `write` the string as-is. If you want to store something more complex, consider the `json` module; if you want something even more flexible and powerful, use `pickle`.
2. Use fixed-length strings. If part of your file format spec is that the name must always be 255 characters or less, just write `'<255s'`. Shorter strings will be padded, longer strings will be truncated (you might want to throw in a check for that to raise an exception instead of silently truncating).
3. Use some in-band or out-of-band means of passing along the length. The most common is a length prefix. (You may be able to use the `'p'` or `'P'` formats to help, but it really depends on the C layout/binary format you're trying to match; often you have to do something ugly like `struct.pack('<h{}s'.format(len(name)), len(name), name)`.)

---

As for why your code is failing, there are multiple reasons. First, `read(11)` isn't guaranteed to read 11 characters. If there's only 1 character in the file, that's all you'll get. Second, you're not actually calling `read(11)`, you're calling `read(1)`, because `struct.calcsize('s')` returns `1` (for reasons which should be obvious from the above). Third, either your code isn't exactly what you've shown above, or `infile`'s file pointer isn't at the right place, because that code as written will successfully read in the string `'m'` and unpack it as `'m'`. (I'm assuming Python 2.x here; 3.x will have more problems, but you wouldn't have even gotten that far.)

---

For your specific use case ("file header… which contains information about the contents; version information, and other string values"), I'd just use `write` the strings with newline terminators. (If the strings can have embedded newlines, you could backslash-escape them into `\n`, use C-style or RFC822-style continuations, quote them, etc.)

This has a number of advantages. For one thing, it makes the format trivially human-readable (and human-editable/-debuggable). And, while sometimes that comes with a space tradeoff, a single-character terminator is at least as efficient, possibly more so, than a length-prefix format would be. And, last but certainly not least, it means the code is dead-simple for both generating and parsing headers.

In a later comment you clarify that you also want to write ints, but that doesn't change anything. A `'i'` int value will take 4 bytes, but most apps write a lot of small numbers, which only take 1-2 bytes (+1 for a terminator/separator) if you write them as strings. And if you're not writing small numbers, a Python `int` can easily be too large to fit in a C `int`—in which case `struct` will silently overflow and just write the low 32 bits.

Comment: I believe the problem here is the data type, should give the length of the string: `'<s11'`

Comment: @askewchan: Almost. But the count comes before the format type, and the string is 11 characters long…

Comment: And also, if you're literally just writing it, then don't use struct, just use `.write()` for a file object (maybe adding a trailing NUL if needs be for some delimiting)

Comment: I'm writing multiple fields to the header, some of them are strings, some ints, which is why I used struct in the first place. Should I just choose sizes for each of my string types?

Comment: @JonClements: Looking at the complete problem, I think a trailing newline is probably just as good as a trailing NUL, and even simpler…

Comment: @TKKocheran: Is there any reason not to read and write the ints, etc. as strings? (Keep in mind that an int takes 4 bytes, while a small int in string format, even with a newline, is 2-3 bytes.)

Comment: @TKKocheran: More importantly: What makes you think the `struct` module is what you want? What advantage over, say, JSON, or just newline-separated `str`, are you looking ofr?

Comment: @abarnert I could write JSON, it'd actually be kind of nice. How do I determine how long I should make the JSON string though, in the header? How can I tell when real actual file data begins?

Comment: @TKKocheran: Well, JSON is actually a self-terminating format, so you can always use [`json.raw_decode`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.JSONDecoder.raw_decode) to decode the JSON header and find the start of the body at the same time. Alternatively, you can use a length prefix (either in text or binary), or a terminator character. You could even move the body into the JSON, instead of having a separate header and body.